# how to make array using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have  list of subjects with checkbox.when user submit selected subjects i am getting properly but i need to make like this if user selected 3subjects(Tamil,Science,English) i want to declare like this var data = {"Subject" :[{subject0:Tamil,subject1:Science,subject3:English}]} someone help me out how to make . i have enclosed my html and controller

```js
.controller('TestController', ['$scope','$http','$window','$location', function($scope,$http,$window,$location,$stateProvider) 
 {
var serverData = ["Tamil", "Science", "English","computer"];
$scope.items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
var modal = {
name: serverData[i],
selected: false
 };
$scope.items.push(modal);
}
$scope.submit = function()
 {
 var checkedItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.items[i].selected) 
 {
      checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
    }
    }
    console.log(checkedItems);
  //Expectation:
//var data = {
//"Subject" :[{subject0:Tamil,subject1:Science,subject3:English}]
//}
}]);
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="TestController">
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
  <li class="item item-checkbox">
     <label class="checkbox checkbox-energized">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" >
     </label>
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="submit()"/>
        
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, beautify your code a little bit, it's horrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :

```
$scope.submit = function()
{
   var checkedItems = [], data = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
     if ($scope.items[i].selected) 
      checkedItems.push("Subject"+i, $scope.items[i].name);
   }
   data.push("Subject", checkedItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do like this.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var checkedItems = [], data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
       if ($scope.items[i].selected)
          checkedItems["Subject" + i] = $scope.items[i].name;
    }
    data["Subject"] = checkedItems;
    console.log(data); // {"Subject" :[{subject0:Tamil,subject1:Science,subject3:English}]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I make it bit more angular way

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerZero">
    {{data.Subject}}

    <ul ng-repeat="item in serverData">
        <li class="item item-checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox checkbox-energized">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.subject[$index]">
            </label>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>

   <input type="button" ng-click="showData()" value="show data">
</div>
```

javascript :

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);


function ControllerZero($scope, Timer) {
    $scope.serverData = ["Tamil", "Science", "English", "computer"];
    $scope.subject = [];
    $scope.data = {'Subject' : [{}]};
    $scope.showData = function() {
        var count = 0;
        $scope.data.Subject[0] = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.subject, function(value, key) {
                if(value === true) {
                    $scope.data.Subject[0]['subject' + count] = $scope.serverData[key];
                    count++;
                }
        })
    }
}


ControllerZero.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

fiddle link : http://fiddle.jshell.net/55zjjyhk/

or you can make it become realtime by put $watch, but seems that unnecessary.

Comment: how can i get selected services .if i put console.log($scope.subject) i am getting Array [ true, true, true, true ] like this

Comment: yo do right, that's the $scope.object, if you want to select services as array, you have to put it in another array.